# Соль в crypt php

Tags: криптография, php, соль

Всем привет.

Изучаю для себя методы шифрования, остановился на функции crypt, но никак не пойму из множества примеров (в том числе на php.net) про соль, что означают данные записи?

```
$salt = '$2a$07$R.gJb2U2N.FmZ4hPp1y2CN$';    
$salt = '$2a$10$';
```

и т.д. Что такое соль, я знаю, но что конкретно в данной функции значат все эти $ и буквы?

Comment: @Stuf, в [доке](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.crypt.php) по crypt все подробно расписано. Это, грубо говоря, идентификатор алгоритма + количество раундов хэширования.

Comment: @Etki доку читал, все равно не понимаю, взять, к примеру, crypt('rasmuslerdorf', '$2a$07$usesomesillystringforsalt$') - что все эти буквы значат в соли? Я, конечно, могу взять просто готовый и не париться, но хочу разобраться все-таки.

Comment: @Stuf, какие именно из букв?

Comment: @Etki $2a$, как я понимаю, пишется всегда? А после него что означают 07$ или 10$, а также многобукав$?

Comment: > Весовой параметр из двух цифр является двоичным логарифмом счетчика итераций низлежащего хэширующего алгоритма, основанного на Blowfish, и должен быть в диапазоне 04-31, значения вне данного диапазона вызовут отказ crypt().

Comment: http://hashcode.ru/questions/329776/php-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0-blowfish

Вот ещё к контексту относится, неплохой ответ.

Comment: Т.е. получается, что $2a$ пишется всегда, 07$ или 10$ это сколько раз функция сгенерирует хеш, а многобукав$  это соль (сам задаю), которая должна быть четко 22 символа?

Comment: @Stuf бнопня - зачем я это писал в первый раз, если сейчас пишу во второй:

> Это, грубо говоря, идентификатор алгоритма + количество раундов хэширования.

$2a$ - blowfish

$2a$07$ - blowfish, 7 раундов

Comment: @Etki спасибо, с этим, видимо, разобрался, остался еще вопрос - если не указывать соль, то при каждом вывозе функции генерируется своя новая соль?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разберем строку:

```
$salt = '$2a$07$R.gJb2U2N.FmZ4hPp1y2CN$';
```

`2a` - это blowfish префикс.
К слову, начиная с версии PHP 5.3.7 используется **[security fix](https://php.net/security/crypt_blowfish.php)**, исправляющий потенциальную возможность high-bit атак. Он добавляет два новых префикса `2x` и `2y`. Префикс `2a` был оставлен с целью обратной совместимости.
`07` - весовой параметр из двух цифр (количество итераций)
`R.gJb2U2N.FmZ4hPp1y2CN` - соль
`$`  - служит в качестве разделителя параметров и обозначения начала и конца строки

`$режим$количество_итераций$соль$`

Comment: Если соль будет меньше 22 символов, функция сама просто забьет 0 до недостающих? И если ее не указать, то при каждом новом вызове будет своя соль генерироваться?